# Return the end of the url if the url contains a certain directory

Tags: php, regex

I need to search thru a sql file and find the filename (the end of the url) where the url contains `/assets/`

Example url:

```
https://www.example.com/assets/screenshots/this-is-an-example/2016-12-20_15-42-29.png
```

It has `/assets/` in it, so I want to get the last part of the url, being:

```
2016-12-20_15-42-29.png
```

Another example:

```
https://www.example.com/images/screenshots/this-is-an-example/2016-12-20_15-42-29.png
```

Nothing would return because `/assets/` was not found.

*The number of directories deep it goes will be different, so it could be `/assets/dir1/dir2/filename.jpg`, and the next could be `/assets/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/filename.jpg`

Hoping this can be accomplished using regular expression.

Comment: Use str_pos() and basename() functions.

Comment: @clearshot66 thanks, looking to use preg_match_all

Comment: You need `/assets(/[^\s/?&#]+)+`. The filename with a leading slash mark is within first capturing group. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/AlR0vu/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(?=.*\/assets\/).*\/\K.*$
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of string.
- `(?=.*\/assets\/)` Positive lookahead to ensure that `/assets/` substring is present in the string.
- `.*` Match anything greedily.
- `\/` Match the last `/`.
- `\K` Reset operator, resets match.
- `.*$` Match anything until end of string `$`.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/GEqoDX/2).

---

Php snippet:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://w...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/assets/screenshots/this-is-an-example/2016-12-20_15-42-29.png';
preg_match('/^(?=.*\/assets\/).*\/\K.*$/',$url,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Prints:

```
2016-12-20_15-42-29.png
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/axAYmZ).

Answer (score 1):

As Outlined, `basename()` will be a nice way to solve this.

However, here's a regex, if you prefer that way (or need it to apply it to some sort of firewall-pattern-fields):

```
@^.*?/assets/.*?/([^/]+\.\w{3})$@
```

(Note the Delimiter `@` cause the pattern contains a lot of `/` - you can ofc. stick to `/` as delimiter, but then you have to escape every `/` in the pattern.)

https://regex101.com/r/wKhMAk/1

Comment: There will be hundreds of url's that will be found in the string. It's a huge string.

Comment: @Brad this information should be added to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

The `strpos()` will check if the search string **/assets/** exist in the url.

If it does exist, it will return the position of the search string from the url provided `$url`. 
If not, it will return false.

Here I make use of the ternary operator (shorthand for if else statement) to evaluate the condition. As said above, if the search string exist, it will return the filename of the path(`$url`) through the function `basename()` else returned empty if the search string is not found.

```
$url = "https://www.example.com/images/assets/screenshots/this-is-an-example/2016-12-20_15-42-29.png";

$endOfUrl = strpos($url, '/assets/') !== false ? basename($url) : '';

echo $endOfUrl;
```

Comment: This will be searching thru thousands of lines.